# Проблема с кодировкой при отправке запросов в приложении rails

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, post, ruby

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему я получаю эту ошибку при отправке любого запроса методом put, post в своём rails-приложении?

> Encoding::CompatibilityError: inspected result must be ASCII only or use the same encoding with default external

```
2.0.0-p648 :001 > Encoding.default_external
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
2.0.0-p648 :002 > Encoding.default_internal
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
2.0.0-p648 :003 > c = Customer.new
 => #<Customer id: nil, ... *какие-то поля*> 
2.0.0-p648 :004 > c.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Encoding::CompatibilityError: inspected result must be ASCII only or use the same encoding with default external
```

База posgresql, в кодировке UTF-8. В файле  application.rb имеется строка config.encoding = "utf-8", а во всех контроллерах и моделях магический комментарий # -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-. То есть я делаю то, что хочет от меня сервер: отправляю запросы в кодеровке равной default external, но это ему не нравится. Единственное подозрение на саму ос (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог только переход на другую версию ruby.